# Problem with passing data from anonymous function in Ajax and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, anonymous

I need to validate a user and password before a form is sent. For that I use jQuery and Ajax. But I have problems passing the `'estado'`value outside the anonymous function.

This is the code:

```
function tx_oriconvocatorias_pi1_validarFormPost(){
    var x=document.forms["form_postulante"]["pass_un"];
    if (x.value==null || x.value==""){
        alert("Por favor ingrese su contraseña.");
        return false;
    }
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var cun = $j('#correo_un').val();
    var pun = $j('#pass_un').val();
    var estado = null;
    $j.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'eID=ori_convocatorias_formPost&correo_un='+cun+'&pass_un='+pun,
        success: function(datos){
            if(datos!=1){
                alert ("La contraseña ingresada no es válida"); 
            }
            estado = datos;
            alert(estado);
        },
    });
    alert(estado);
    if (estado!=1){
        return false;
    }
}
```

I notice that the first `alert(estado)`(outside) returns null and then the second `alert(estado)` (inside)  returns `'datos'`, so the last `alert(estado)` in the code is executed first and always my function returns `false`.

I don't know how to evaluate `'estado'` after execute the Ajax code and not before.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You are doing an asynchronus request so your function ends before the result of the ajax call has returned.
You can force the call to be synchronus :

```
$j.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'eID=ori_convocatorias_formPost&correo_un='+cun+'&pass_un='+pun,
        async: false,//here you are synchrone
        success: function(datos){
```

or you can return false, and submit your form manually.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first `alert(estado)` is null and the second `alert(estado)` is 'datos', is because ajax is asynchronous. This means that even though you are calling $j.ajax, the code is still going through and evaluating the rest of the function.

I think this might be something more of what you're looking for:

```
function tx_oriconvocatorias_pi1_validarFormPost(){
    var x=document.forms["form_postulante"]["pass_un"];
    if (x.value==null || x.value==""){
        alert("Por favor ingrese su contraseña.");
        return false;
    }
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var cun = $j('#correo_un').val();
    var pun = $j('#pass_un').val();
    var estado = null;
    $j.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'eID=ori_convocatorias_formPost&correo_un='+cun+'&pass_un='+pun,
        success: function(datos){
            if(datos!=1){
                alert ("La contraseña ingresada no es válida"); 
            }
            estado = datos;
            alert(estado);
        },
        error: function(datos) {
            return false;
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code you wrote is not exactly what I need, but you're right about that I was using asynchronous when I must use synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use synchronous call in order to achieve this. But with synchronous ajax calls the browser will not respond untill the response comes keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I don't have problem with this delay because the function is used to validate a form against a database before it is sent.